# Regex for replacing numbers to characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a string such as `"kdf343kkkk4k4"`. I need to find the numbers on this string and replace a number with a specific character like `'X'`. Output should be like `"kdfXXXkkkkXkX"`.

Each and every number should be replaced with `'X'`:

```
343 = XXX
```

I tried with regex replace but it replaces all together.

```
343 = X
```

I am using the following regular expression:

```
x.replaceAll("([0-9])+", "X");
```

Please explain to me how to do this.

Comment: Leave out the parentheses and the `+` sign.

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
x = x.replaceAll("\\d", "X");
```

you don't need **+**, with it you specify that "one or more" digits are going to be replaced with a single X

Comment: @owlstead I was adding the part were I was explaining the + when I remember that \\d is even shorter than [0-9]

Comment: "you don't need +" -- in fact, in this case, you don't _want_ `+`

Answer (score 3):

In your regular expression remove the **+** `symbol`

i.e.

```
x.replaceAll("([0-9])", "X");
```

And do not forget to re assign it back,As String is immutable in java

```
  x= x.replaceAll("([0-9])", "X");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
String name = "Test656887";
name = name.replaceAll("[0-9]","X");
System.out.println(name);
```

**Method 2:**

```
 String name = "Test656887";
 name = name.replaceAll("\\d","X");
 system.out.println(name);
```